# Bind a property of the WPF Image

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have the following WPF UserControl
[image]

I want that the blue border be displayed only when the object has its (dependency bool property) property **IsSelected** to true.

Is that possible?

```
<Canvas>

    <Image x:Name="Dot">
        <Image.Source>
            <DrawingImage>
                <DrawingImage.Drawing>
                    <DrawingGroup>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                                <Pen Brush="Blue" Thickness="2" x:Name="BigCircleThickness"/>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Pen>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="BigCircle" Center="0,0" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"/>
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                        <GeometryDrawing>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                                <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue" />
                            </GeometryDrawing.Brush>
                            <GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                                <GeometryGroup>
                                    <EllipseGeometry x:Name="SmallCircle" Center="0,0" RadiusX="2" RadiusY="2"/>
                                </GeometryGroup>
                            </GeometryDrawing.Geometry>
                        </GeometryDrawing>
                    </DrawingGroup>
                </DrawingImage.Drawing>
            </DrawingImage>
        </Image.Source>
    </Image>

</Canvas>
```

In other words, I need that when `IsSeleted = false` "BigCircle" dissapear.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `DataTrigger`. Something like this:

```
<Image>
    <Image.Style>
        <Setter Property="Source" Value={StaticResource MyDrawingImage_NoBorder}" />
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsSelected}" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Source" Value={StaticResource MyDrawingImage_WithBorder}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Image.Style>
</Image>
```